# Problème de composer le pronom relatif

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

*Ce village s’appelle Colombey où le Général de Gaulle est né // Ce village où le Général de Gaulle est né s’appelle Colombey

---

La première est bizarre, la deuxième est correcte. Mais si l'on se demande pourquoi, comment l'expliquez-vous?

ps: Je suis étranger. Expliquez facilement, s'il vous plaît.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je crois que c'est parce que le pronom relatif *où* se rapporte au nom *village*, plutôt qu'à *Colombey*. Comme vous le dites, la première est étrange plutôt que complètement fausse. On pourrait l'utiliser pour un effet de style.

Answer (score 2):

La phrase peut être décomposée comme ça :

> [Ce village] [s'appelle] [Colombay] [où le Général de Gaulle est né]
>
> [sujet] [verbe] [complément]←[subordonnée]

La subordonnée est une sorte de "mini-phrase" dans la phrase, elle peut aussi être décomposée.

- Ici la subordonnée se rattache au complément. Normalement on peut le faire, mais *où* doit se rattacher à un **lieu**, mais ici le complément est un **nom de ville**, pas une **ville**.

Quand on dit "*Je m'appelle Pierre*", *Pierre* ne désigne un **nom**, pas une **personne**.

> [J'][arrive] dans [la ville] [où le Général de Gaulle est né]
>
> [sujet][verbe] [complément]←[subordonnée]

Cette phrase est correcte car la subordonnée se rattache bien à un lieu.

C'est la même chose pour :

> [Ce village] [où le Général de Gaulle est né] [s’appelle] [Colombey]
>
> [Sujet]←[subordonnée] [verbe] [complément]

Comment: merci beaucoup.

Comment: @TeleportinGoat - You might want to mention that "Ce village s’appelle Colombey où le Général de Gaulle est né" is actually not incorrect. Maybe rare, maybe poetic, but entirely possible :-)

Comment: @Frank Tu es sûr ? Je ne suis pas figé dans mon avis là-dessus mais je vais avoir besoin d'arguments pour changer d'avis ^^ Pour moi ça ne se dit pas. Est-ce que c'est que la subordonnée fait indirectement référence au sujet, "Ce village" ou c'est qu'elle se réfère au complément quand même ? Pour moi, ça serait comme dire "*Il s'appelle Pierre qui est mon ami*".

Comment: Oui, je suis sûr. Ce n'est pas impossible en poésie ou dans un discours, ou sermon, pour un effet de style qui met l'accent sur _Colombey_, quoique peut-être avec une virgule: _ce village s'appelle Colombey, où le Général de Gaulle est né_. C'est même assez beau, en fait.

Comment: Ainsi, d'après la théorie de Goat, "Il s'appelle Pierre qui est mon ami" est impossible. Pierre n'est que un nom, pas une personne.

Comment: @Frank donc quelque chose qui se rapproche de l'idée d'une [antanaclase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclase) ou d'un zeugme ? Je vois vaguement l'idée. Toujours est-il que j'ai aucune source extérieure ou argument grammatical pour affirmer que c'est correct. Dans le doute, vaut mieux ne pas en parler à des gens qui apprennent la langue.

Comment: Dans un discours ça passe très bien: " ce village s'appelle Colombey! où le Général de Gaulle est né..." avec accent sur Colombey. On sent toute la fierté qui en ressort pour les habitants de Colombey. L'effet est très différent de la proposition originelle, mais ça passe très bien. On peut imaginer une série de _où ..._ qui suivent pour donner plus de détails sur ce village en particulier, qui s'appelle Colombey.

Comment: @Frank Désolé mais non ^^ Tu peux mettre toute la ponctuation que tu veux, moi je vote pas pour quelqu'un qui fait un discours comme ça. (en plus du fait que préciser le nom d'un village (explicitement comme ça) ça exprimer l'inverse de la fierté)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat - bon ben ça ne te convient peut-être pas, mais moi ça me va. Faut de tout pour faire un pays et une langue :-)

Comment: J'espère que de Gaulle n'a rien à voir avec tout ça - aucun de mes commentaires n'était motivé par la politique, et je n'ai personnellement aucune attache avec Colombey. J'ai aussi demandé à d'autres Français en France ce qu'ils pensaient de cette phrase, et ils n'y voyaient aucun problème non plus, si ce n'est qu'elle est beaucoup moins commune. En tout cas, elle n'est pas incorrecte d'un point de vue grammatical.